# How to get button to act as column search filter within ag-grid and search for a set list of items?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

**SUMMARY:** I have a column for ids within an ag-grid table. How can I get a button-click to only display some of the rows (for which I have a list of ids), while not re-writing the whole table?

**BACKGROUND:** I am using the community version of ag-grid and am using it with Javascript. I have a column with the id numbers in it. When I click a button (or something else eventually, but start with a button for simplicity), is it possible for it to act as a filter within the table, and hence could be undone by clicking another button to clear the filter?

In case that wasn't cleaar, I am looking to do:
1. Click button1
2. Display certain rows within a table whose id numbers are in my list variable
3. Have this button1's action act as a filter that can be undone by a button2 (which could be programmed perhaps like a clear filter button)

Is this possible to do with a quickfilter? Otherwise, if this isn't possible, how could I do this when over-writing the table, whilst still having the option to 'instantly' revert back to the original table

(I don't think I need to add code as I am unsure of how to build in this functionality)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible. Look at [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/#example-filter-api) in the docs.

Comment: @thirtydot - thank you very much